# the difference between ref and array schema type of reference in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

creator: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
})

creator: [UserSchema]

What is the difference between the two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

*(To make things a little easier to explain, I will call the model that `creator` is a property of, `Blog`)*

```
creator: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' } }
```

This declares a `creator` property that stores a reference (basically, an `ObjectId`) to a `User` document. It's sort of like a foreign key in SQL.

When you perform a query on the `Blog` model, you can tell Mongoose to automatically load the referenced document using ["population"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). This is necessary because the `User` documents are stored in a separate collection (they are, in that respect, standalone).

```
creator: [UserSchema]
```

This declares a `creator` property that stores a list of users. These users have their own Mongoose schema (used for validation), but the main difference is that they don't get stored in a separate collection; in other words, each `User` document is just stored as-is in the `creator` array of a `Blog` document (Mongoose calls these ["sub-documents"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)).

This is somewhat faster, because to load a particular `Blog` document you have to perform just one query (instead of one for the `Blog` document and an additional one for the `User` document if you would be using population), but it's less flexible and depending on the size of the array (the number of users you will be storing) you may run into certain MongoDB limits.

Comment: So if the user schema has a property called skill and I want to query the creator schema to populate all post created by users with a certain skill can I write: post.find({user.skill: query}).populate('post').exec(err, function()). If yes then which of the two lines of code will be the best to do so.

Comment: @dtytomi when using the first method, you need to use the [`match`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) property of `populate()` to find posts that were created by a user with a particular skill. For subdocuments, you _can_ query for it directly. One method isn't necessarily better than the other, it depends on the exact use case.